# V2: add values to a file on server Receive sensor data, publish on webpage

Tags: php, get

I want to read a php file on my web server (data to be sendt from arduino in future)

**Code idea I got here:**
(http://www.glacialwanderer.com/hobbyrobotics/?p=15)

I use this URL http://192.168.0.5/xPortTest.php?value0=111&value1=222

on server I have this code file:
xPortTest.php

**Responce:**

> Failed to open file

I'm not a programmer so I need a helping hand to get this code return my values 111 and 222

**Code:**

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET["value0"]) || !isset($_GET["value1"])) {
  echo "Error: You need to pass in valid _GET parameters. Script Terminated.";
  exit;
}

$value0 = $_GET["value0"];
$value1 = $_GET["value1"];

$fp = fopen("./xportTest.txt", 'at');
if (!$fp) {
  echo "Failed to open file";
  exit;
}

$outputstring = "$value0 $value1\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring));

echo "\0";

?>
```

All I have done is added this code to the original:
if (!isset($_GET["value0"]) || !isset($_GET["value1"])) {

Comment: @KenLee the `a` flag should, like `w`, attempt to create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `t` is a Windows-specific flag that converts line endings. (Vs. `b` that forces binary aka as-is.) See [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for the modes/flags.

Comment: Looked it up myself while checking the flags. :) Leia, can you confirm that **1** your error reporting is turned on? "_Upon failure, an E_WARNING is emitted_" for `fopen`, which may give you some clues. **2** Are you on Windows or Linux? If latter, check that you have write permissions to the folder.
_